# Django do not create locale po file for my project

Tags: django, localization

Looks like django do not want create/update `.po` file for my project (or django do not know that i'm using any other languages).

```
# mkdir locale
# python manage.py makemessages --all
# ls locale/
# (empty dir)
```

however:

```
# mkdir locale
# python manage.py makemessages -l ru-ru
# ls locale/
# ru-ru  (will create ru-ru directory)
```

but if a do modification in this file, then do `compilemessages -l ru-ru` - django will not use apply it, and seems like this modification does not react on anything.

Here is my `settings.py`:

```
TIME_ZONE = "Europe/Moscow"
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
   'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
   'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
   'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
   "account.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware",
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
  'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
  'django.core.context_processors.debug',
  'django.core.context_processors.request',
  'django.core.context_processors.media',
  'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
  'django.core.context_processors.tz',
)
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to set [LOCALE_PATHS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths) too

Comment: Great - glad it worked. If you're happy, can you please accept this answer? (click the outlined tick)

Comment: This didn't work for me, I have defined `LOCALE_PATHS`, set `USE_TZ` to True and added `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` as a `MIDDLEWARE` in `settings.py`. When I execute `python manage.py makemessages -l fr` or `django-admin makemessages -l fr`, the command outputs `processing locale fr` but no `.po` files are created. My project is in `C:\projects\{project_name}` so I superstitiously ran it with admin rights but that didn't cut it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create .po files one by one if they don't exist yet:

```
django-admin makemessages -l ru-ru
```

Then you can use -a/--all argument that updates all .po files:

```
django-admin makemessages -a
```

In addition to that, setting [LOCALE_PATHS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths) is also needed.

Answer (score 2):

If any translation string changed in your code you need to do two steps.

First you need to update your existing message files with `django-admin.py makemessages -a` and second, compile your `.po` files with `django-admin.py compilemessages`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files.