# Django locale .po files not showing up in locales folder

Tags: python, django, locale, gettext

I have been running into an issue setting up locales for my Django app. When I run the `django-admin`'s `makemessages` command no resulting `.po` files show up in my `{project_root}/locales` folder.

Here are the steps I followed to setup locales:

**Created locale/ folder in project root**

**Changes to settings.py**

```py
from os.path import join as osjoin

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
]


USE_I18N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    osjoin(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
```

**Solved missing dependencies**
Had to install [GNU gettext (for windows)](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html) and added it to system PATH.

**Commands I ran**

```bash
python manage.py makemessages -l fr
```

also tried:

```bash
django-admin makemessages -l fr
```

I also tried with the `fr_FR` tag, didn't change anything.

both result in this output message but no files added to `locales/`:

```
processing locale fr
```

I also superstitiously tried to run the command as admin but didn't change much.

I am also aware of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611112/django-do-not-create-locale-po-file-for-my-project) to the same question (9 years ago) but the answers didn't help.

Comment: Do you... have any text marked for translation? If so, can you provide an example? I could imagine, that in a completly empty project with no translated string, no po file is generated...

Comment: and where are you running this "makemessages" command? I always run it in the directory of tha *app* I want to localize, not the *project*

Comment: I am running it in my `poetry` environment, through the `run` command not in the shell.

Comment: No i don't have any text marked for translation yet, I didn't know it was a prerequisite. If this is necessary could you please elaborate, I am not sure I understand.

Comment: I don't know about poetry, but for me it did matter where I executed this command.
On the project level (containing the settings.py file) it did nothing, running it in an app folder did the trick.

Do you have any calls to translate text? Do you use the blocktranslate template tags? Or use gettext/gettext_lazy in the py files? In short, _Is there anything to translate yet?_
I could imagine, that there is no output, if there is nothing to translate

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean and no, I haven't made any translation calls yet. I was following a tutorial on setting up locales for django and it wasn't mentioned that I had to do things in that order. I'll try this out and keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check File Structure
2. Correct Locale Path
3. Check Language Code
4. Run makemessages from Project Root
5. Check for Permissions
6. Check for Messages to Translate
   from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
   python manage.py makemessages -l fr -v 2

Comment: Thanks for the response, points 1 to 5 have already been checked with no success, could you explain the sixth point better please ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need make 'locale' directory in root .
django cant make this folder.

Comment: The locale folder is present in the project's root directory. Also added one in the main app to be sure but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: if you have error in console attach error message. by error message we can help better .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't have any errors in console, only what I said, no result when running the makemessages command

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got a typo error.

Change this

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    osjoin(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
```

To

```
# import os .. place on top
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
```

Then run your command again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not the issue. I tend to import very precisely and only what I need out of a package. I forgot to include this import in my code snippet, which makes things unclear. I have imported `os.path.join ` as so `from os.path import join as osjoin`. I will update my code snippet.